# Python: Printing Tasks for the logged in user

Tags: python

Please, assist as I am a newbie with this.

I need to have the tasks printed for the user that is logged in.

- Add the following functionality when the user selects ‘vm’ to view all the
  tasks assigned to them:
- Display all tasks in a manner that is easy to read. Make sure that
  each task is displayed with a corresponding number which can be
  used to identify the task.
- Allow the user to select either a specific task by entering a number
  or input ‘-1’ to return to the main menu.
- If the user selects a specific task, they should be able to choose to
  either mark the task as complete or edit the task. If the user
  chooses to mark a task as complete, the ‘Yes’/’No’ value that
  describes whether the task has been completed or not should be
  changed to ‘Yes’. When the user chooses to edit a task, the
  username of the person to whom the task is assigned or the due
  date of the task can be edited. The task can only be edited if it has
  not yet been completed.

user.txt

```
admin, adm1n
Peter, Peter
Amy, A3y
```

task.txt

```
Peter, Peter has a new task, Testing the task manager, 20/09/2022,Yes
Amy, First new task, Checking the first new task, 21/09/2022,Yes
admin, Admin to assign tasks, Admin is the main user that has to assign all tasks, 29/09/2022, No
Peter, Find Wally, Find Wally somewhere behind the grave yard, 31/09/2022, No
```

My code thus far:

```
elif menu == 'vm':
        pass
        def view_more():
            username = new_task_username
            num_task = 0
            with open('tasks.txt', 'r') as f:
                view_more = f.read()
            for row in view_more:
                field = row.strip().split(",")
                num_task += 1
                if username == field[0]:
                    print("Task Number: " + str(num_task) + "\nUsername: " + field[0] + "\nTitle: " + field[1] + "\nDescription: " + field[2] + "\nDue Date: " + field[3] + "\nCompleted: " + field[4] + "\n")

            editTask = input("\nWould you like to edit a task? (Edit) or return to the menu? (-1)\n")

            def _edit_file(taskComplete):
                userTask = taskFile[taskNum].strip().split(",")
                new_state = taskFile[taskNum].strip().replace(userTask[4], taskComplete)
                print(new_state)
                updated_string = view_more.replace(taskFile[taskNum].strip(), new_state)
                with open('tasks.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(updated_string)

            if editTask == "Edit":
                taskNum = int(input("Please enter the Task number?\n"))
                taskNum = taskNum - 1
                with open('tasks.txt', 'r') as file:
                    taskFile = file.readlines()
                for line in taskFile:
                    print(taskFile[taskNum] + "\n")
                    break

                taskComplete = input("Has this task been completed?\n")
                if taskComplete == "Yes":
                    _edit_file(taskComplete)

                elif taskComplete == "No":
                    _edit_file(taskComplete)

                elif editTask == "-1":
                    menu()

        view_more()
```

It does not print:

````
if username == field[0]:
                    print("Task Number: " + str(num_task) + "\nUsername: " + field[0] + "\nTitle: " + field[1] + "\nDescription: " + field[2] + "\nDue Date: " + field[3] + "\nCompleted: " + field[4] + "\n")
    ```
````

Comment: @mkrieger1
I need help to have the tasks printed for the user that is logged in.

Comment: What is the problem with printing the tasks for the user that is logged in?

Comment: If I select VM it goes straight to asking me if I want to edit instead of printing the tasks for the user that is logged in.

Comment: Maybe `username` is not equal to `field[0]`?

Comment: Use ```print(username)``` and ```print (field[0])```at the end of the block to check if each variable has the value you think it has. You can also use ```print ('"' + username + '"')``` to detect white spaces.

Comment: I recommend reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.